# In android how to find out mobile location inside building

Tags: android, geolocation, gps, bluetooth-lowenergy, google-beacon-platform

I want to implement an app which can track employee inside the office building.Our office building is 3 floors(with ground floor) which contain 2640 square feets. To achieve this i have search and find about the location in android using that we can get latitude,longitude and altitude(elevation) to find the location of user but the problem with this process is the altitude(elevation) is not changing when i tested.

After some more research i find out about google beacon which can help to advertise when a mobile is near by.

[Google Beacon](https://developers.google.com/beacons/get-started)

But the problem is there is some functionalities are not working now like send notifications near by, and i'm unable to find more information regarding this beacons.

If anyone knows there is a better way to do please help me. I have worked on location tracking but never worked on something like this, to track a person inside a building and which room he is.